# AddChild with GetChildByName

Tags: actionscript-3

Complete AS3 noob here - I've tried Googling this, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for (I stumbled across this, http://ub4.underblob.com/as3-naming-elements-dynamically/, but it doesn't weem to work for me).

I'm trying to dynamically add a Movieclip inside another Movieclip through an external AS3 class

Something like this:

```
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(x, y, "right");

var stageBackground:MovieClip = (stage.getChildByName("back") as MovieClip);

stageBackground.addChild(bullet);
```

However, while this compiles correctly, at run time, I get error #1009 - Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

The debug panel tells me the problem is with this line:

```
stageBackground.addChild(bullet);
```

But I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it. I've tried recasting `stageBackground` as a Sprite, but that didn't change anything. I know the MovieClip back exists - when I reference it through near identical code in my document class, it works perfectly.

Comment: 1) trace stageBackground, if it is null, then there are no miracles, somewhere the code or logic is wrong. 2) can you show the "near identical code"? 3) how and when the "back" is created and added to stage?

Comment: The error indicates that there is no `MovieClip` with the name `back` added to the `stage`. How does `back` get created and added to the display?

Comment: Does the child has the ".name" variable assigned to "back"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `stage` here to find your container, which is very likely the problem.

You are probably thinking that the `stage` property refers to "the stage" in Adobe Flash authoring environment.
That's not true.

If you placed a MovieClip on "the stage" in the Flash IDE, it ends up on the main time line, this however, is not the thing the `stage` property is referencing. `stage` is the topmost `DisplayObjectContainer` in the display list. It only exists at runtime. It more or less represents the FlashPlayer window, the runtime environment that executes your .swf file.

In short: you are simply looking for your back `MovieClip` in the wrong place.
The property of a container that represents the main timeline is `root`.

**Do not use root either.**

As you can see, your code becomes dependent on the display list
structure of your application. You are already struggling to find the
container that you are looking for. If you change the structure, your code breaks. Even changing the name of the container (for example to something like "background") will wreak havoc.

**Instead, use Events.**

You are in another class and you want to fire a bullet.
So you create that bullet same as you do now:

```
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(x, y, "right");
```

Next, dispatch an `Event` to notify the rest of your code that a bullet was created and it should be placed in the appropriate container:

```
dispatchEvent(new BulletEvent(BulletEvent.CREATED, bullet));
```

(Create a custom event class `BulletEvent` that extends `Event`, with the apropriate setter and getter for a `Bullet` object)

Register a listener on the object of your class that creates the bullets, you will catch this event and place the bullet in the container:

```
var object:YourClass = new YourClass();
object.addEventListener(BulletEvent.CREATED, addBulletToContainer);

function addBulletToContainer(e:BulletEvent):void
{
    // adding the bullet to the container
    back.addChild(e.bullet);
}
```

This code would be placed in the parent of your back `MovieClip`.
The Flash IDE automatically creates variables behind the scenes that have the same names as the instance names. That's why the variable `back` is available here.

Using events here allows you to literally fire the bullet into your code with somebody else taking care of it, where it's easy to figure out the container it belongs into.